# sqlite3 is not opening pre-populated database second time

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, cordova-sqlite-storage

I'm exploring sqlite 3 plugin and I found one weird issue which I didn't found through out web.

I'm working on android .So, in asset folder I have a database with some data. The database name was `sqliteexample.db`.
Then I used below code to open database. And it was a success.

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var db = SQLite.openDatabase(
  {
    name: 'sqliteexample',
    createFromLocation: '1'
  },
  () => {
    console.log('db connection success');
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('db connection error');
    console.log(error)
  },
);
```

Now, In order to check different scenario's I renamed the database file name to `sqliteexample1.db`. Then I changed it on code as below

```
{
    name: 'sqliteexample1',
    createFromLocation: '1'
  },
```

That's all, I started getting error `cannot open database`.

**How internally It was accessing It ?

And If I skip `createFromLocation: '1'` will it create a new database ?**

Kindly anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple,

if data file is named the same as the dbName

```
SQLite.openDatabase({name : "sqliteexample", createFromLocation : 1}, okCallback,errorCallback);
```

if data file is named different than dbName

```
SQLite.openDatabase({name : "sqliteexample", createFromLocation : "~sqliteexample1.db"}, okCallback,errorCallback);
```

if your folder is not in app bundle but in app sandbox

```
SQLite.openDatabase({name : "sqliteexample", createFromLocation : "pathroot/data/mydbfile.sqlite"}, okCallback,errorCallback);
```

The thing is file name and database name need not be same always.